# Define FastAPI query parameter other way than by function argument

Tags: python, fastapi

I have API specification and there is a `from` query parameter for one endpoint.

I have chosen FastAPI as my framework but I can not use normal way how to define query parameters in FastAPI as `from` is Python keyword, i.e. this is illegal:

```py
@server.post("/test")
def test(from: str):
    return []
```

Is there any way how to work around this limitation?

Comment: Does [this](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/query-params-str-validations/#alias-parameters) help?

Comment: It does, thanks a lot!